ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.distutils'
An error occured while installing the wrf-python library.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [6 lines of output]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-oyk6_k1z\wrf-python_4d4fb187dd8b475c900ed0c20f1b8158\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
      import numpy.distutils.core
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.distutils'
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
------------------------------

I am trying to install the packages wrf-python and gdal. An error occured while installing the packages.


You are using python 3.12 as numpy.distutils are removed in python 3.12.

You can install python 3.11 or python 3.10 separately and run
pip install wrf-python




Latest version of wrf-python was released:
Released: May 26, 2022
https://pypi.org/project/wrf-python/
numpy.distutils

numpy.distutils has been deprecated in NumPy 1.23.0. It will be removed for Python 3.12; for Python <= 3.11 it will not be removed until 2 years after the Python 3.12 release

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/distutils_status_migration.html#status-of-numpy-distutils-and-migration-advice

pypi lists compatibility of wrf-python up to python3.9, so 3.10 and 3.11 might also not work

Thank you for your comment on my query. I successfully installed the WRF at Google Colab using this version combination. I will try installing it on my system.

@FlyingTeller it is working for python 3.10 because it was released March 2022 while python 3.10 was released Oct 2021.

That is a faulty line of reasoning. Nothing forced the package maintainers to actually provide python3.10 support, simply because it was already available.

I checked in on python Python 3.10.12 it is working. Also, there are tons of packages which mention older versions of python but they work for the new ones as well. Pypi website is not updated for every version of python.

Okay... However, I have Python 3.9 installed on my system. I will try using the upgraded version of python also. Earlier I was trying to install the required numpy version but still, I could not run this on my system. Thanks for your reply. I will try again and come back with the updates...
